# Problems with dynamic array creation using pointers

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a 2d dynamic array using the values of an array of `int` as my pointers. I don't know how to put this in words exactly, so here is the code.  Maybe you'll understand what I'm trying to do if you see it.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    const int length =5;
    int arr[5]={1,1,3,9,1};
    int* AR[length];

    for (int i=0; i<length;i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<(arr[i]); j++){
            AR[i] = new int (arr[i]);
            AR[i][j]=93;
            cout<<"["<<AR[i][j]<<"] ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<arr[i]; j++) {
            delete[] AR[i];  
            delete []&AR;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I run it with `arr[] < 4` it runs perfectly, but if the size of `arr` exceeds 4 values it crashes.  Can you see why?

Comment: Your indentation is killing me.  Chances are that if you indented your code properly, you would realize what some of your mistakes were.  (You have things in loops that shouldn't be).

Comment: Your use of psudo-haxxor speak is killing me.

Comment: You are calling `delete[]` about 75 times. That cannot be correct.

Comment: Could you use `std::vector<std::vector<int> >` or `std::array<std::array<int> >`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem too:

```
 AR[i] = new int[arr[i]]
```

or

```
 AR[i] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * arr[i])
```

---

Explanation:

```
 int * a = new int(5);
```

Creates an integer, set its to 5, and returns a pointer to it.

```
 int * a = new int[5];
```

This allocates space for 5 integers, and returns a pointer to the first.

**EDIT:**  Also your deletes need to be adjusted

```
 for(int i = 0; i < first_dimension; ++i)
    delete [] AR[i];

 delete [] AR;
```

**EDIT 2:** As Wug points out, you have a memory leak as well.  Your code will work for now, but every "j" iteration, you allocate new memory for the dynamic array essentially losing access to your previously allocated dynamic single dimension array.

---

Here's a super awesome website for learning dynamic memory allocation:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/

Comment: There is still more to it than this.  The allocations are in the wrong place.

Comment: Well, cplusplus.com is not particularly well regarded here. It contains a lot of errors, promotes misconceptions (STL is NOT standard C++ library) and poor programming practices

Answer (score 1):

You were allocating memory in your inner loop instead of your outer loop, something you'd have caught if your indentation was consistent.  Also, you were using `new int(arr[i])` instead of `new int[arr[i]]` (the former allocates one int and sets its value to `arr[i]`, the latter allocates an array of `arr[i]` ints.

In your second loop, you were repeatedly freeing a stack variable, which is a double nono - You only free allocated memory once, and you don't free variables declared on the stack.

Here's cleaned up code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
                             // moved outside of inner loop
    AR[i] = new int[arr[i]]; // used int[arr[i]] instead of int(arr[i])
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i]; j++)
    {
        AR[i][j] = 93;
        cout << "[" << AR[i][j] << "] ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    delete[] AR[i]; // removed incorrect delete statement and incorrect inner loop
}
```